# How to run exe in mono in the background

Tags: c#, linux, unix, debian

Okay, so I have a .net exe, and it runs when I type `mono myexe.exe`. However, if I want to use another command or close the terminal window the app stops executing.

I have tried using `mono myexe.exe &` and it runs and showing [8] 20078 etc., but once I type something else it shows [8]+  Stopped, and then executes the command I typed in.

Any ideas?

Comment: See http://www.mono-project.com/FAQ:_Technical (Can I run Mono applications without using 'mono program.exe'?)

Answer (score 5):

how about `nohup mono myexe.exe &`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `&` then look into outputting the result to a file.

`nohup mono program.exe > program.out &`

The *right way* of doing this would be to create a daemon with your linux distro.

Answer (score 2):

You can also run it as an service using this line of code:

```
mono-service -l:/tmp/myservice.lock ./ServiceDaemon.exe
```

where `-l:LOCKFILE` specifies the file to use for locking. When you look into your lock file, you will see the process id. The process id you can use to kill the service, whenever you need to terminate it.

Source: [blog.chudinov.net](http://blog.chudinov.net/demonisation-of-a-net-mono-application-on-linux/)